# Launching a GUI object from a different class

Tags: java, user-interface

I have a start menu I created which launches a separate GUI that I made. However, when I try to launch it nothing happens. I made the initialization public and called that function but nothing works. Here's what I'm working with:

This is the button that is supposed to launch the other window.

```
// start the program from the first lesson
        JButton btnStart = new JButton("Start");
        btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                PianoGUI gui = new PianoGUI();
                gui.initialize();
            }
        });
```

This is the code with the other GUI (obviously not the entire code, just what's relevant):

```
public void initialize() 
    {
        int width = 1280;
        int height = 720;
        int wKeyWidth = width/17;
        int bKeyWidth = wKeyWidth*3/4;
        int bKeyPos = wKeyWidth*5/8;


        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        Button btnDb3 = new Button("");
        btnDb3.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        btnDb3.setBounds(bKeyPos+wKeyWidth*0, 0, bKeyWidth, 290);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnDb3);
```

My question is this: Obviously

```
PianoGUI gui = new PianoGUI();
gui.Initialize();
```

Doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
public void initialize() 
    {
        int width = 1280;
        int height = 720;
        int wKeyWidth = width/17;
        int bKeyWidth = wKeyWidth*3/4;
        int bKeyPos = wKeyWidth*5/8;


        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        Button btnDb3 = new Button("");
        btnDb3.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        btnDb3.setBounds(bKeyPos+wKeyWidth*0, 0, bKeyWidth, 290);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnDb3);

        JButton btnC3 = new JButton("");
        btnC3.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        btnC3.setBounds(0, 0, wKeyWidth, 471);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnC3);

        Button btnEb3 = new Button("");
        btnEb3.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        btnEb3.setBounds(bKeyPos+wKeyWidth*1, 0, bKeyWidth, 290);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnEb3);

        JButton btnD3 = new JButton("");
        btnD3.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        btnD3.setBounds(wKeyWidth*1, 0, wKeyWidth, 471);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnD3);

        JButton btnE3 = new JButton("");
        btnE3.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        btnE3.setBounds(wKeyWidth*2, 0, wKeyWidth, 471);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnE3);

        Button btnGb3 = new Button("");
        btnGb3.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        btnGb3.setBounds(bKeyPos+wKeyWidth*3, 0, bKeyWidth, 290);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnGb3);

        Button btnAb3 = new Button("sharp");
        btnAb3.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        btnAb3.setBounds(bKeyPos+wKeyWidth*4, 0, bKeyWidth, 290);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnAb3);

        Button btnBb3 = new Button("sharp");
        btnBb3.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        btnBb3.setBounds(bKeyPos+wKeyWidth*5, 0, bKeyWidth, 290);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnBb3);

        JButton btnF3 = new JButton("");
        btnF3.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        btnF3.setBounds(wKeyWidth*3, 0, wKeyWidth, 471);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnF3);

        JButton btnG3 = new JButton("");
        btnG3.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        btnG3.setBounds(wKeyWidth*4, 0, wKeyWidth, 471);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnG3);

        JButton btnA3 = new JButton("");
        btnA3.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        btnA3.setBounds(wKeyWidth*5, 0, wKeyWidth, 471);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnA3);

        Button btnDb4 = new Button("");
        btnDb4.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        btnDb4.setBounds(bKeyPos+wKeyWidth*7, 0, bKeyWidth, 290);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnDb4);

        JButton btnB3 = new JButton("");
        btnB3.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        btnB3.setBounds(wKeyWidth*6, 0, wKeyWidth, 471);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnB3);

        JButton btnC4 = new JButton("");
        btnC4.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        btnC4.setBounds(wKeyWidth*7, 0, wKeyWidth, 471);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnC4);

        Button btnEb4 = new Button("sharp");
        btnEb4.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        btnEb4.setBounds(bKeyPos+wKeyWidth*8, 0, bKeyWidth, 290);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnEb4);

        JButton btnD4 = new JButton("");
        btnD4.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        btnD4.setBounds(wKeyWidth*8, 0, wKeyWidth, 471);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnD4);

        JButton btnE4 = new JButton("");
        btnE4.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        btnE4.setBounds(wKeyWidth*9, 0, wKeyWidth, 471);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnE4);

        Button btnGb4 = new Button("sharp");
        btnGb4.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        btnGb4.setBounds(bKeyPos+wKeyWidth*10, 0, bKeyWidth, 290);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnGb4);

        JButton btnF4 = new JButton("");
        btnF4.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        btnF4.setBounds(wKeyWidth*10, 0, wKeyWidth, 471);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnF4);

        Button btnAb4 = new Button("sharp");
        btnAb4.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        btnAb4.setBounds(bKeyPos+wKeyWidth*11, 0, bKeyWidth, 290);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnAb4);

        Button btnBb4 = new Button("sharp");
        btnBb4.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        btnBb4.setBounds(bKeyPos+wKeyWidth*12, 0, bKeyWidth, 290);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnBb4);

        JButton btnG4 = new JButton("");
        btnG4.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        btnG4.setBounds(wKeyWidth*11, 0, wKeyWidth, 471);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnG4);

        JButton btnA4 = new JButton("");
        btnA4.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        btnA4.setBounds(wKeyWidth*12, 0, wKeyWidth, 471);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnA4);

        JButton btnB4 = new JButton("");
        btnB4.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        btnB4.setBounds(wKeyWidth*13, 0, wKeyWidth, 471);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnB4);

        Button btnDb5 = new Button("sharp");
        btnDb5.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        btnDb5.setBounds(bKeyPos+wKeyWidth*14, 0, bKeyWidth, 290);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnDb5);

        Button btnEb5 = new Button("sharp");
        btnEb5.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        btnEb5.setBounds(bKeyPos+wKeyWidth*15, 0, bKeyWidth, 290);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnEb5);

        JButton btnC5 = new JButton("");
        btnC5.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        btnC5.setBounds(wKeyWidth*14, 0, wKeyWidth, 471);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnC5);

        JButton btnD5 = new JButton("");
        btnD5.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        btnD5.setBounds(wKeyWidth*15, 0, wKeyWidth, 471);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnD5);

        JButton btnE5 = new JButton("");
        btnE5.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        btnE5.setBounds(wKeyWidth*16, 0, wKeyWidth, 471);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnE5);

        JTextArea lessonText = new JTextArea();
        lessonText.setEditable(false);
        lessonText.setBounds(10, 537, 1380, 201);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lessonText);

        JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton_2.setFont(new Font("Gill Sans MT Condensed", Font.BOLD, 24));
        btnNewButton_2.setBackground(new Color(210, 180, 140));
        btnNewButton_2.setBounds(0, 471, 176, 65);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_2);

        JButton button_2 = new JButton("New button");
        button_2.setFont(new Font("Gill Sans MT Condensed", Font.BOLD, 24));
        button_2.setBackground(new Color(210, 180, 140));
        button_2.setBounds(173, 471, 176, 65);
        frame.getContentPane().add(button_2);

        JButton button_3 = new JButton("New button");
        button_3.setFont(new Font("Gill Sans MT Condensed", Font.BOLD, 24));
        button_3.setBackground(new Color(210, 180, 140));
        button_3.setBounds(345, 471, 176, 65);
        frame.getContentPane().add(button_3);

        JButton button_4 = new JButton("New button");
        button_4.setFont(new Font("Gill Sans MT Condensed", Font.BOLD, 24));
        button_4.setBackground(new Color(210, 180, 140));
        button_4.setBounds(520, 471, 176, 65);
        frame.getContentPane().add(button_4);

        JButton btnNext = new JButton("Next");
        btnNext.setFont(new Font("Gill Sans MT Condensed", Font.BOLD, 24));
        btnNext.setBackground(new Color(210, 180, 140));
        btnNext.setBounds(1224, 471, 176, 65);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNext);

        JButton btnBack = new JButton("Back");
        btnBack.setFont(new Font("Gill Sans MT Condensed", Font.BOLD, 24));
        btnBack.setBackground(new Color(210, 180, 140));
        btnBack.setBounds(1050, 471, 176, 65);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnBack);
    }
```

Comment: You have to call **gui.setVisible(true);** at some point. Usually done after calling **gui.initialize()**

Comment: What does the Initialize method in the PianoGUI class look like or does PianoGUI extend the other GUI? We need more info.

Comment: So would that be a separate function in the `PianoGUI` class?

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis I can post more information if you need it. I was trying to reduce the amount of code I posted because it's pretty long.

Comment: Well, you say nothing is happening. It could be that the code is being called and it just appears that nothing is happening from a UI perspective. Are you for certain the code in the initialize is not being called? Have you debugged this?

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis I added the code now. Sorry it's long.

Comment: I did debug it and yes, it does actually call the initialization function.

Comment: ok. Did you try gui.setVisible(true); as suggected by @JayC667 ?

Comment: Yes I did. `setVisible` comes up with a red line under it.

Comment: It doesn't compile because your GUI class didn't expose the setVisible method of the underlying JFrame. You need to call the setVisible on the frame, not on the GUI.

Comment: Something interesting I just noticed. I actually don't need `gui.Initialize()` because it already creates the object. Still doesn't launch,but I just discovered that.

Comment: @ErikPragt It worked! Thank you!